# Export all the users from an Active Directory server to CSV

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to make a command in PowerShell to export all the users from an Active Directory server to a CSV file. It should include name, last name and status.

I tried running:

`Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} | Select-Object SamAccountName,Name,Surname,GivenName | Format-Table`

I received this error:

> "Get-ADUser" not found.

Comment: Is this a question? What have you tried? Why didn't it work to your satisfaction? Right now this isn't even a question as it is missing any kind of problem and question mark.

Comment: My bad, updated.

Comment: Did install the RSAT Tools? Otherwise the PowerShell module won't be available. What happens if you `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`?

Comment: It worked now after i added this command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is working fine for me and is working like expected. Though your current output is a table rather than CSV. You could look into `Export-Csv` for that.

What might be/is missing if it tells you that it's an unknown command is the actual module. In order to have the `ActiveDirectory` module available you will have to have the RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) installed for AD. They're available as a separate download for Windows 7 and/or might be available as an OS Feature.

You can check which modules are available by running `Get-Module -ListAvailable` and to see which are currently loaded you can run `Get-Module`. If you want to load a module (like the `ActiveDirectory` module) you can use `Import-Module`.

In your case it should look like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"} | Select-Object SamAccountName,Name,Surname,GivenName | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```